# Default value for input in C++

Tags: c++

In pythons prompt_toolkit, you can set a default value for a prompt, simply by doing this

```py
from prompt_toolkit import prompt
prompt("no edit me", default = "Hello world!")
```

This would allow the user to edit the `Hello world!` displayed on the screen, but not the `no edit me` displayed on the screen. Is there a way I can do this in c++?

Comment: Please post your C++ code & what is it you want to have a default for.

Comment: @Holt This question is far from the dupe.

Comment: `prompt_toolkit` works with the terminal and changes the content. You can't do this with standard C++ but you can use a library to achieve the same behavior. For Windows you would use conio and for linux you would use ncurses.

Comment: @ThomasSablik How so? Please elaborate.

Comment: @ThomasSablik [PDCurses](https://pdcurses.org) is available for Windows :)

Comment: @Holt OP is asking for a terminal manipulation like you can do with ncurses or conio. OP wants to output a text that can be changed in the terminal.

Comment: @ThomasSablik that’s exactly the dupe question...

Comment: @Holt The question in the dupe is if it's possible with `std::cin`. It's not possible. Here the question is how it can be done. The answer is with conio, ncurses or pdcurses. That's a different question and different answers.

Comment: @ThomasSablik Feel free to re-open vote. I stand on my ground, those are similar questions as far as my understanding of SO dupe goes. Also, feel free to post an answer to the dupe mentioning conio, ncurses or pdcurses, I don't see why it would not fit there. There is much more value in having a single thread with a "This can't be done with standards." and "But this can be done with ....", than having two separate ones for the initial problem.